# SpringBoot Kotlin - Could not compute caller for function: private final fun

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, interface

Currently, I try to use SpringBoot in combination with Kotlin and creating an interface with some methods with default behavior.

When all the methods are public in the interface everything is fine. But as soon I try to make a helper method private I get the following example error message:

```
Could not compute caller for function: private final fun [....] member = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow private members in interface  and kotlin based on java so they are same one  programming language like it said in oracle(java) doc [Java Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) :

> "The Java programming language provides mechanisms for access control,
> to prevent the users of a package or class from depending on
> unnecessary details of the implementation of that package or class."

Access control is all about hiding implementation details. An interface has no implementation to hide.